# How to combine conditional probabilities into one expression?

Tags: probability

## Question

Find $\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(Y)}\right)$ where $f(.)$ is a monotonic function, $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables. The pdf of $\zeta \in \{ X, Y\}$ is $f_{\zeta}(\zeta)$ with $\zeta \geq 0$.

## Answer

\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(Y)}  \right) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(y)} \right) \right]\, f_{Y}(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \\
\end{align*}

We have the following two cases:

**Case $I$: when  $f^{-1}(0) >0 $**
$$
\mathcal{A}_{I1}=\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(y)}\, | \, f(y) \leq 0\right) 
\quad
\text{and}
\quad 
\mathcal{A}_{I2}=\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(y)}\, | \, f(y) > 0\right)
$$

**Case $II$: when $f^{-1}(0) \leq 0 $**
$$
\mathcal{A}_{II1}=\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(y)}\, | \, f(y) \leq 0\right)
\quad
\text{and}
\quad 
\mathcal{A}_{II2}=\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(y)}\, | \, f(y) > 0\right)
$$

## My Issue

Now I want to write one expression for each case (combine the subcases); hence, I need to find $\mathbb{P}(f(Y) > 0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(f(Y) \leq 0)$. What I did is write down these probabilities as follows:
$$
\mathbb{P}(f(Y) \leq 0)=F_{Y}(f^{-1}(0))
\quad
\text{and}
\quad 
\mathbb{P}(f(Y) > 0)=\mathbb{P}(Y > f^{-1}(0))= 1-F_{Y}(f^{-1}(0))
$$
Then we have
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(Y)}  \right)
= 
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(f(Y) \leq 0)\mathcal{A}_{I1}+\mathbb{P}(f(Y) > 0)\mathcal{A}_{I2}, \quad f^{-1}(0) >0  \\
\mathbb{P}(f(Y) \leq 0)\mathcal{A}_{II1}+\mathbb{P}(f(Y) > 0)\mathcal{A}_{II2}, \quad  f^{-1}(0) \leq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

*But this is wrong because it isn't logical.* To illustrate this further, let us look at case $II$ first. If $ f^{-1}(0)$ is negative. Then, $\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(Y)}  \right)$ is $\mathcal{A}_{II1}$ if $f(Y) \leq 0 \Rightarrow Y \leq f^{-1}(0)$, but we know $X_1$ is greater than or equal to zero from its pdf; thus $\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(Y)}  \right)$ *can not be* $\mathcal{A}_{II1}$, so it has to be $\mathcal{A}_{II2}$. But $F_{Y}(g^{-1}(0))=1$ here; hence there's a contradiction. How to fix this?

## What do I need to find a combined expression?

If I want to compute $\mathbb{P}\left( X > \sqrt{f(y)}\right)$ for a certain set of parameters; then I can compute $g^{-1}(0)$ and decide which case I should be using. But, I can not decide which sub-case should be considered because I can not know if  $f(y)$ is greater, less, or equal to zero since $y$ is a random variable. The only thing I know is the distribution of $y$ (hence $g(y)$ too). As such, I can only *associate* with one of the sub-case based on the probability of the event of $f(y)$ being greater, less, or equal to zero. And that is what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Sorry but why do you embark on these sign considerations if your goal is to solve the problem on the other page, where $f(0)>0$?

Comment: @Did why did say it is zero? It depends on the parameters because it’s a subtraction. We can’t guarantee it’s positive, can we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several notation issues here that makes the reasoning (and the related question) hard to follow. For example, you are writing $\mathcal{A}_{I1}$ using a conditional probability, but the condition is not a random event. Let me change the statement and notation a little.

We want to compute

$$p=P[X^2 > g(Y)]   \tag{1}$$

where $g(\cdot)$ is a continuous strictly increasing function, $X,Y$ are continuous independent non-negative random variables with well behaved densities $f_X,f_Y$. Then

$$p = \int_0^\infty P[X^2 > g(y)] \, f_Y(y) \, dy  \tag{2}$$

If $g(y)<0$ in $[0,\infty)$ then $p=1$ trivially. If there is a root $a\ge 0 $, with $g(a)=0$, then we can split the integral to get

$$\begin{align}
p &= \int_0^a f_Y(y) \, dy + \int_0^a P[X > \sqrt{g(y)}] \, f_Y(y) \, dy   \tag{3}\\
&=F_Y(a) + \int_a^\infty (1-F_X(\sqrt{y})) f_Y(y) \, dy  \tag{4}\\
&=1 - \int_a^\infty F_X(\sqrt{y}) f_Y(y) \, dy \tag{5}\end{align}$$

If there is no such non negative root, then we get the same expression with $a=0$. Then we can define $a^*$ as the non-negative root of $g()$ if it exists, $0$ elsewhere, use any of the above formulas - for example, if you prefer, $(5)$ we get:

$$p=1 - \int_{a^*}^\infty F_X(\sqrt{y}) f_Y(y) \, dy \tag{6}$$

That's all. I don't understand why you make it so complicated. If you insist on writing $(3)$ in terms of probabilities, notice $P(g(Y)>0)=P(Y\ge a^*)$. Anyway, you won't get rid of the integral, as you  notation seems to imply...

Update:
IF $g(y)= r (y^2 +s)^t - u$ , with all constants positive, then : first we can discard the case $g(y) <0$ $\forall y$. Second, the tentative positive root is $a=\sqrt{ (u/r)^{1/t}-s}$ ; there is no root if $rs^t >u$ (in which case $g(y)>0$ always). Hence you simply have to plug this in $(5)$:

$$ a^{*}=\begin{cases} \sqrt{ (u/r)^{1/t}-s} & rs^t <u\\
0&{\rm otherwise}\end{cases} \tag{6}$$

Comment: I will restate what I understood form your answer: If $g(y) < 0$, the $p=1$. If $g(y)=0$, still $p=1$. But if $g(y) >0$, we find the root $a=g^{-1}(0)$. Now, if $a \geq 0$, we use $(5)$. If $a < 0$, we use $(5)$ with $a=0$. Up until here I’m fine. But, if I try to compute this using MATLAB for certain parameters, then how would I know whether or not $g(y)$ is greater, less, or equal to zero? I can’t. The only thing I know it its distribution. That’s why I need an expression that accounts for all cases and calculates $p$ based on the probability that $g(y)$ is greater, less, or equal to zero.

Comment: I don't get you. Can you calculate (or assert non-existence) the root of $g$ or not? If not, why? If yes, then you have $a^*$ and you are done.

Comment: @leonbly $g(y)=\left( \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1} \right)^{1/\gamma_2} (y^2+\beta_1^2)^{\gamma_1/\gamma_2} - \beta_2^2$. Let $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\gamma_1=\gamma_2=1,\beta_1= 6 \, \text{and} \, \beta_2=8$. Then $g(Y)= Y^2 -28$, now compute $p=\mathbb{P}\left( X^2 > g(Y)  \right)=\mathbb{P}\left( X^2 > Y^2 -28 \right)$. What expression should I use? It depends on $g(Y)$. If $g(Y)<0 \Rightarrow Y^2 < 28$, then $p=1$, $g(Y)>0 \Rightarrow Y^2 > 28$, then $a=\pm \sqrt{28}$ and $p$ is $(5)$ with lower limit $+\sqrt{28}$ (right?). But we don't know. Is $p=1$? Is  $p$ computed from $(5)$? That's my issue.

Comment: I frankly don't understand your issue. See my update.

Comment: Thank you for the update and please bear with me as I’m a bit unhandy with probabilities. If $g(y)$ is of the form you described, why would $g(y)$ be omitted? How did you conclude it’s alway either zero or positive? Also, does this mean that now $p$ is given by one equation $(5)$ with $a*$ given in $(6)$? One more question regarding $(3)$, I think there’s a typo and the second integral is from $a$ to $\infty$, correct?

Comment: Also one more thing, I think the confusion here is because in my opinion, the event $g(y) \leq 0$ (or $g(y)> 0$) is random, because $y$ is a random variable; but you seem to think otherwise as you stated in the beginning of your answer. Could you elaborate on that? Thank you again, I hope I’m not too much of a trouble.